# Extracting function from sensor

Tags: functions

and sorry if I am on the wrong stackexchange.

I have a problem. I have collected data from a distance sensor and extracted its function with respect to temperature. The data extracted proved that the sensor is completely linear (mx + b).

The problem is that at different distances, the m and b coefficiente of the lines change. Of course b will change, but my problem is with the m coefficient. The slope coefficient changes according to the real distance and as stated above the distance read changes according to temperature in a very linear manner.

How would I go about extracting this behaviour and putting it into a function.

**EDIT:**

Ok. I was not very clear, so I'll try to add more information.

I noticed that my sensor was behaving very strangely during hot days. This is normal for well ... everything, however this specific distance sensor I'm using is incredibly more sensitive to temperature.

With that problem I tried analyzing my sensor's behaviour over temperature and noticed that the output distance changes with temperature in a line (mx + b). This behaviour repeats itself for several distances. I noticed that m and b coefficients change according to its actual distance (the m coefficient has the A*e^(-D*b)+c, where D is the real distance).

So, distance measured changes with temperature, slope (m) coefficient changes with real distance, as well as c.

Since I can't actually know the real distance and my code has to give ma that information, I was trying to regress a function that could give me this information.

However, if I try to regress it according to mx+b, it will work correctly over a small distance range, and I can't use real distance (I think) for the m and c coefficients because I don't know it. How would I go about measuring the distance using only the temperature and given distance by the sensor? Is it possible?

Below it's possible to see what I'm talking about. The x axis is temperature, the y axis is measured distance and the different lines are the lines at 5 different distances (5, 4, 3, 2 and 1 m)

[image]

Comment: I am unclear what you are measuring and how the temperature is involved. What is $mx+b$? Is it the distance? the temperature? Could you describe the setup a little more clearly.

Comment: @almagest mx+b is distance over temperature (this sensor is heavily dependant on temperature). I placed the sensor at a distance and collected data accross several temperatures and it gave me the mx+b behavior. It does that for all distances. m coefficient changes according to the real distance. I'll try to add some more info to the question

Comment: I am still not clear what you are saying. Are saying that the distance $d$ is a function of temperature $T$ and some other parameter $v$ such as voltage or current. So you have $d(v,T)=m(v)T+b(v)$? In any case, I think this is a practical data science question rather than a math question, although it might turn out to have a math element. But either way, there is not much hope of saying anything useful without seeing some actual data.

Comment: @morcillo. Your question is incomprehensible. If you cannot explain clearly what is the problem then joint to your question a example of the measurements on a numerical table.

Comment: @almagest I modified the question to make it more understandable

Comment: @JJacquelin I'll try adding some graphs so that you can see it better

Comment: @almagest I just added an image. x is temperature. I just saw your comment stating it looks more  like a data science problem. And I was in a hurry ind didn't realize that. I should change this question to the data science stackexchange

Comment: ok for the graph, that makes your question much clear. But  to avoid to go and take the values from the graph , pls. also add  the corresponding table.

Comment: @GCab That could be a problem. The table for each line consists of about 100k points.

Comment: ok, you added $m(D)$ as being an exponential,  then how does $b$ change wrt $D$ ?

Comment: @GCab the same way

Comment: What I would like to see (as a table) is the $(m_i,b_i)$ for each of the lines in your plot.

Answer (score 2):

PRELIMINARY COMMENT :

The data is not given on the form of numerical table. A "subsitute" of data was made thanks to scanning the graph provided by the OP. This isn't an accurate way. As a consequence the below numerical results are more or less biaised.

ANSWER TO THE QUESTION :

As far as I can understand the question, it seems that it is a simple problem of fitting a function $y(x,D)$ of two variables. $x$ is the variable on the horizontal axis of the graph. $D$ is the so called "Distance". $y$ is the value of the function on the vertical axis.

A very simple function can be :
$$y(x,D)\simeq (a+bD)x+(p+qD)$$
$a,b,p,q$ are the parameters which can be approximately computed thank to a classical linear regression.

The result is (The fitted function is represented by the black lines)  :

[image]

Of course a much better fitting can be obtained with more terms in the polynomial function, for example :

$$y(x,D)\simeq (a+bD+cD^2+dD^3)x+(p+qD+rD^2+sD^3)$$

$a,b,c,d,p,q,r,s$ are the parameters which can be approximately computed thank to a classical linear regression.

The result is (The fitted function is represented by the black lines)  :

[image]

Instead of polynomial function one could use other kind of functions $f(D)$ and $g(D)$ :
$$y(x,D)=f(D)x+g(D)$$
For example those functions might include exponentials. But the regression would be non-linear which requires more complicated and difficult methods generally iterative.

Answer (score 0):

(im newbie here, feel free to delete this comment if offtopic

distance=(temperature*x + b)

but sometimes x and b changes - it seems its relationship is "almost linear", but not 100% linear

1. you can use differences
   distance=distance[2:length(distance)]-distance[1:(length(distance)-1)]
   similiar to temperature

maybe relationship between "changes of distance" is linear to "changes of temperature"

2. i consider error, as something to be forecasted
   (but often, predictions are worse then "good constant mean"... sometimes is better to accept linear relationship you already have, even with errors

ahaaa you have like not 1 equation..but 5 equations
so its not    distance=(temperature*x + b)... .x and b increase with distance
i feel now its not about forecasting but picking right x and b.
but u said it " extracting this behaviour and putting it into a function."

(btw i dont know the answer just trying)

*edit:*
so you know distance, for example at distance 2, equation is distance=(temperature*x + b)
when you have distance 3.123456 there is equation(temperature*xother + bother)

**you already know which values to assign to x=, b= ... according to "start distance"** you just dont want to search for them manualy, but via mathematics :D
seems so clear now .. but sry i dont know how to calculate it

Comment: Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @morcillo hello, can I ask .. you have data, you looking for function getMB(startDistance) { ...code ....return(m,b) } ... (no advertising) if you have data in excel, this custom function use your data and then return m,b .... i dont know how to create math equation, but i can (help) create this excel sheet with data and 1 simple custom function that use your data